# Get the last 3 months from the time of the last order date

Tags: mysql

My task is to get the total commission in the last 5 months. This is my code. I am using mysql.

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, " ", a.last_name) AS sales_reps,
       YEAR(c.order_date),
       ROUND(SUM((d.quantity_ordered*d.price_each)*.01), 2) AS commission_last_6mos
FROM employees a
LEFT JOIN customers b ON b.sales_rep_employee_no=a.employee_no
LEFT JOIN orders c on b.customer_no = c.customer_no
LEFT JOIN order_details d ON c.order_no = d.order_no
WHERE job_title='Sales Rep'AND c.order_date >= CURDATE()- INTERVAL 5 MONTH
GROUP BY  CONCAT(a.first_name, " ", a.last_name)
ORDER BY commission_last_6mos DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I have also used now(). They do not show any results.

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: If you replace **CURDATE()** with **NOW()** in the WHERE clause, it should work

Comment: @ARRiyad It is not working still. I have already used all the ways I could find on the internet, but to no avail.

Comment: Please post the schema, sample data and sample output

Comment: As requested by others, please update your question with [relevant DDL and sample data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)? A well asked question is more likely to get useful answers! This query is [non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and if your server was configured (_"correctly"_) with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled, you would be getting a 1055 error. Do yourself, and everyone else, a favour and use meaningful table aliasing. Why `employees a` when `employees e` makes more sense?

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like the table containing job_title is not specified. If it is in the table employees, then you should have a.job_title, for example. For the time range, try:

AND c.order_date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

For more information about the DATE_SUB function, check out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp

Comment: If I don't include this line "AND c.order_date >= CURDATE()- INTERVAL 5 MONTH", there is a result. But this pertains to all time. And I am looking for the last 6 months.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the time range issue.

Comment: OP's use of `CURDATE()- INTERVAL 5 MONTH` is perfectly valid, and _arguably_ more readable than `DATE_SUB()`